# How to check if specific pattern precedes some character?

Tags: java, regex, regex-lookarounds

I am new into java regex and I could't find an answer.

This is my regex: `-?\\d*\\.?\\d+(?!i)`
and I want it **not** to recognize eg. `String 551i`

This is my method:

```
private static double regexMatcher(String s, String regex) {
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s.replaceAll("\\s+", ""));

    if (!matcher.find()) {
        return 0;
    }
    String found = matcher.group();

    return Double.parseDouble(matcher.group());

}
```

I want this method to return 0.0 but it keeps returning 55.0.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an atomic group to avoid backtracking into the whole digit dot digit matching pattern:

```
"-?(?>\\d*\\.?\\d+)(?!i)"
```

See the [Java demo](http://ideone.com/q5VBaV) and a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/8g0vAL/2).

Comment: Can u help me one more thing? Why does this regex recognizes `-0.501` as **-0**? And how do I make it not to?

Comment: The regex [matches the number as expected](https://regex101.com/r/8g0vAL/1). I [cannot repro](http://ideone.com/s7Lto0).

Comment: Sorry I meant `-0.501i ` as **-0**? Is there any quick solution with my regex?

Comment: Use an atomic group - `-?(?>\d*\.?\d+)(?!i)`